# Unauthorized exception when uploading contents in Plone with transmogrifier

Tags: python, plone, transmogrifier

When running a transmogrifier pipeline, and creating new objects, I get an Unauthorized exception on creating certain content types (for example "Document" - 
it is raised at `plone.app.transmogrifier.atschemaupdater.py` 
on this call: `event.notify(ObjectInitializedEvent(obj))`

It is extremely annoying because there is no stack trace on the console. It is also hard
to debug, since there are a lot of inner Plone and Zope calls doing dynamic functions
that "subscribe to events". So far I got this stacktrace with the PDB:

```
Pdb) zope.component.subscribers((event.object, event), None)
*** Unauthorized: You are not allowed to access 'save' in this context
(Pdb) where
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/ZServer/PubCore/ZServerPublisher.py(31)__init__()
-> response=b)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py(443)publish_module()
-> environ, debug, request, response)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py(237)publish_module_standard()
-> response = publish(request, module_name, after_list, debug=debug)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py(115)publish()
-> object=request.traverse(path, validated_hook=validated_hook)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/BaseRequest.py(501)traverse()
-> subobject = self.traverseName(object, entry_name)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/BaseRequest.py(326)traverseName()
-> ob2 = namespaceLookup(ns, nm, ob, self)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.traversing-3.13.2-py2.7.egg/zope/traversing/namespace.py(112)namespaceLookup()
-> return traverser.traverse(name, ())
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.traversing-3.13.2-py2.7.egg/zope/traversing/namespace.py(327)traverse()
-> name=name)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py(120)queryMultiAdapter()
-> return sitemanager.queryMultiAdapter(objects, interface, name, default)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/registry.py(238)queryMultiAdapter()
-> objects, interface, name, default)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.interface-3.6.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/adapter.py(532)queryMultiAdapter()
-> result = factory(*objects)
  /home/gwidion/simples/carta/plone/src/cartacapital.portal.migration/src/cartacapital/portal/migration/import.py(17)__init__()
-> tr("cartacapital.portal.migration")
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/collective.transmogrifier-1.3-py2.7.egg/collective/transmogrifier/transmogrifier.py(62)__call__()
-> for item in pipeline:
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/plone.app.transmogrifier-1.2-py2.7.egg/plone/app/transmogrifier/atschemaupdater.py(67)__iter__()->{'_path': u'/Plone...economia', '_type': 'Folder', 'debug': None, 'state': 'published', ...}
-> event.notify(ObjectInitializedEvent(obj))
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.event-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/event/__init__.py(31)notify()
-> subscriber(event)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/event.py(24)dispatch()
-> zope.component.subscribers(event, None)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py(136)subscribers()
-> return sitemanager.subscribers(objects, interface)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/registry.py(321)subscribers()
-> return self.adapters.subscribers(objects, provided)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.interface-3.6.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/adapter.py(585)subscribers()
-> subscription(*objects)
> /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/event.py(32)objectEventNotify()
-> zope.component.subscribers((event.object, event), None)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py(136)subscribers()
-> return sitemanager.subscribers(objects, interface)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/registry.py(321)subscribers()
-> return self.adapters.subscribers(objects, provided)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/zope.interface-3.6.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/adapter.py(585)subscribers()
-> subscription(*objects)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFEditions-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFEditions/subscriber.py(60)objectInitialized()
-> return webdavObjectEventHandler(obj, event, comment=comment)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFEditions-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFEditions/subscriber.py(44)webdavObjectEventHandler()
-> maybeSaveVersion(obj, comment=comment, force=False)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFEditions-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFEditions/utilities.py(123)maybeSaveVersion()
-> pr.save(obj=obj, comment=comment)
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFEditions-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFEditions/CopyModifyMergeRepositoryTool.py(294)save()
-> self._assertAuthorized(obj, SaveNewVersion, 'save')
  /home/gwidion/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFEditions-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFEditions/CopyModifyMergeRepositoryTool.py(428)_assertAuthorized()
-> raise Unauthorized(name)
(Pdb)
```

My workaround to this up to now has been monkeypatching zope.event.notify to a no-op
prior to running the pipeline, but that is obviously not the way to do it.

Of note: I trigger the transmogrifier pipeline with a function in a view's code - (and I do load the view as site admin, of course).

Comment: Have you tried disabling versioning?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: no. Let me try that. (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.transmogrifier#disable-enable-versioning-sections )

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That indeed worked - can you promote it to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should disable versioning when running a transmogrifier pipeline. This is [documented](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.transmogrifier#disable-enable-versioning-sections) in the `plone.app.transmogrifier` documentation; the `plone.app.transmogrifier.versioning` blueprint offers an easy drop-in recipe for toggling this:

```
[transmogrifier]
pipeline =
    schemasource
    disable_versioning
    constructor
    enable_versioning
    schemaupdater

[disable_versioning]
blueprint = plone.app.transmogrifier.versioning.disable

[constructor]
blueprint = collective.transmogrifier.sections.constructor

[enable_versioning]
blueprint = plone.app.transmogrifier.versioning.enable
```